# Create array of multiple objects with different structure from array of objects with duplicate keys using Object.assign() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an initial array of objects in the following structure:

```
let sampleArray = [
  { chairperson: 'Sample person' },
  { chairperson: 'Sample person 2' },
  { arbitratorClaimant: 'Sample person 3' },
  { arbitratorRespondent: 'Sample person 4' },
  { secretary: 'Sample person 5' }
]
```

I am using

```
Object.assign({}, ...sampleArray)
```

to combine the array of objects into a single object, but since the object cannot have duplicate keys, it overwrites the first chairperson ('Sample person') with the second chairperson. Instead, I would like to output an array with multiple objects where objects with duplicate keys are put into the next object in the array. For instance, this is what I am looking for:

```
[
  {
    chairperson: 'Sample person',
    arbitratorClaimant: 'Sample person 3',
    arbitratorRespondent: 'Sample person 4',
    secretary: 'Sample person 5'
  },
  {
    chairperson: 'Sample person 2'
  }
]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but would it make sense?!? What is the reasoning behind separating the second chairperson from the first object? And what about similar situations in other positions? Would it not be a better solution to create an array for the property "chairperson" and collect both values in there?

Comment: I'm restructuring the data for use in a React app - I'm outputting a table in my app and need to loop over an array of objects to output a new row in the table for each object. The four properties of each object represent each column in the table, so I ultimately need an array of objects with each property in the same position for output in the table

Comment: Why can't your initial data be how you want without having a structure that you need to fiddle about with on the front end? That would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Andy True, and it's entirely possible that I've designed the data model in a poor manner. It's a bit of a complicated model though, and requires multiple many-to-many relationships with join tables; when I make a GET request for the data, I can't think of a way to structure the data model in a way that it would output it in any easy way to work with

Comment: Sorry if I came off combative, I wasn't having a go. I'm running the same gambit with my work at the moment. Data modeling is difficult. @GregKing

Comment: @Andy Didn't come off combative at all! You make a good point, and I appreciate your input. It's worth another look at the data model to see if I can make any improvements. But you're right - data modeling is difficult!

Comment: Choose a sensible model from the start and use GraphQL.

Comment: I guess my other question would be how do you determine (with your current model) whether `arbitratorClaimant` etc should be with sample person A, or B? @GregKing

Comment: GraphQL will only beneficial if the backend data model works otherwise you're just going to face more problems @firstlast.

Comment: @Andy Well there is actually a bit of preprocessing occurring to get to the initial sampleArray shown here. Essentially, the model contains a table of arbitration cases with information on that case, and a many-to-many relationship between that table and an "individuals" table (names of people). There is a join table between those two that holds the IDs of the case and the individual, and a field for the role that individual served in the arbitration case. I'm outputting a table in my react app of the individuals, with a column for each role. I want to make a vertical list of names under each

Comment: @Andy To continue my comment, maybe I could simply achieve the same look without having to use a table and just use lists instead; that way I could loop over arrays of each group of names individually so that they don't have to be structured correctly for rows in a table

Comment: Maybe you could just add a new API endpoint, so instead of getting a massive joined collection of data, you could get the arbitration data with one API call, and the people linked to the case (which I assume they're linked to with a case ID) with another. That may be easier to manage. @GregKing

Comment: @Andy That may indeed make things easier - I'll do some work with my endpoints to see how I can retrieve the data better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example `collated` is similar to @CarstenMassmann's first alternative data structure. This is quite possibly an over-involved way of doing it but the second part of the code essentially pivots (I think that's the right term) the data in collated so that it can be used for table rows.

```js
let sampleArray = [
  { chairperson: 'Sample person' },
  { chairperson: 'Sample person 2' },
  { arbitratorClaimant: 'Sample person 3' },
  { arbitratorRespondent: 'Sample person 4' },
  { secretary: 'Sample person 5' }
];

const merge_objects = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Object.entries(obj2).reduce(
    (acc, [key, val]) =>
      Object.assign(acc, { [key]: (acc[key] ?? []).concat(val) }),
    obj1
  );

const collated = sampleArray.reduce(
  (acc, val) => merge_objects(acc, val),
  {}
);

const max_item_count = (input) =>
  Math.max(
    ...Object.values(input).map((arr) => arr.length)
  );

const get_table_rows = (input) =>
  Array
    .from({ length: max_item_count(input) })
    .map(
      (row, index) =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(collated)
            .map(([key, val]) => [key, collated[key][index] ?? null])
            .filter(([key, val]) => val)
        )
    );

console.log( JSON.stringify(get_table_rows(collated)) );
```

Comment: This does work to format the data correctly, thank you! I need to dig into this a bit further to make sure I understand how this is all working, but I appreciate your help with this. This, combined with the other comments in this thread, have gotten me thinking about how I'm structuring the data model for this application, though

Answer (score 0):

This is - not yet - an answer but an attempt to discuss the desired result.

How about creating a result like the following:

```
  {
    chairperson: ['Sample person','Sample person 2'],
    arbitratorClaimant: 'Sample person 3',
    arbitratorRespondent: 'Sample person 4',
    secretary: 'Sample person 5'
  }
```

Looking at your comment, maybe the following could work for you:

```
  {
    chairperson: 'Sample person, Sample person 2',
    arbitratorClaimant: 'Sample person 3',
    arbitratorRespondent: 'Sample person 4',
    secretary: 'Sample person 5'
  }
```

Instead of the "`,` " any other separator could be chosen for lists of multiple names

Comment: Copied my comment from above: I'm restructuring the data for use in a React app - I'm outputting a table in my app and need to loop over an array of objects to output a new row in the table for each object. The four properties of each object represent each column in the table, so I ultimately need an array of objects with each property in the same position for output in the table. I'm not sure how I would loop over the above object to output multiple rows in the table

Comment: Addressing your update: The problem with simply comma-separating the names is that there are cases where many names will be needed for the same column in the table; the appearance that I'm looking to achieve in the table is to have a new row for each name with the same role